# Wired 802.1x configuration saving credential button

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, batch, ieee802.1x

Dears,
I am creating a batch script that would import .1x configuration on wired user authentication method, however its working without a problem and it prompts me to enter user credentials to connect on the network. however when I logoff the network drops because the credentials I put are not saved.
Work around is to go to Authentican tab on the Network device and Additional Settings and click on "Save credentials" button which will let me put the network credentials and it will save them somewhere and I can logoff and logon fine with network enabled and working.
Is there a way to feed my batchscript registry key or my network profile.xml file in order to emulate the "Save Credential" button so it saves it?

thanks!